# Writing to cloud firestore collection results in permission denied in R

Tags: r, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

### Goal

Write data to collections in a Google Cloud Firestore Database using REST API in R. I am following this [post](https://gabrielcp.medium.com/introduction-to-working-with-firestore-in-r-99443489b01b). At the moment, there are no collections/document in the database.

### Reproducible example

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

sign.up <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  #https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-create-email-password
  r <- POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=", api_key), 
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
            body = toJSON(list(email = email, password = password, returnSecureToken = TRUE),auto_unbox=TRUE))
  return(content(r)) 
}

sign.in <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  #https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password
  r <- POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=", api_key),  
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
            body = toJSON(list(email = email, password = password, returnSecureToken = TRUE),auto_unbox=TRUE))
  return(content(r))
}


my_auth_info <- sign.up("babloo@someemail.com", "examplepass", api_key)
```

The `my_auth_info` provides a result that means it is working. Now, I want to be able to read, write and delete data on the firestore database. So, I use the following functions:

```
read.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  r <- GET(sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint), 
           add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json", 
                       "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)))
  return(r)
}

write.db <- function(db_endpoint, data, auth_token) {
  r <- POST(sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint), 
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json", 
                        "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)), body = data)
  return(r) 
}

delete.db <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token) {
  r <- DELETE(sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", db_endpoint), 
              add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json", 
                          "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)))
  return(r)
}
```

Then I created some `data` and tried to write it as follows:

```
data <- toJSON(list(fields = list(name=list("stringValue" = "Gabriel"), 
                                  favoriteNumber=list("integerValue" = "32343"))),
               auto_unbox=TRUE)


write.db("projects/CloudFirestoreDemo/databases/cloudfirestoredemo-2b423/documents/mydata", data, my_auth_info$idToken)
```

but it resulted in error:

```
Response [https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/CloudFirestoreDemo/databases/cloudfirestoredemo-2b423/documents/mydata]
  Date: 2023-08-30 19:55
  Status: 403
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
  Size: 748 B
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied on resource project CloudFirestoreDemo.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
...
```

By the way, the rules on cloud firestore are:

```
rules_version = '2';
  service cloud.firestore { 
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} { 
      allow read, write; 
    } 
  } 
}
```

What am I missing here? Why do I get this error?